# VCenter Adding Host - Error "conflicts with an existing datastore in the datacenter that has the same URL"

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, dell, vmware-vcenter

We have a new Dell VRTX box (2 Blades & Shared Storage).  We are getting the above error when trying to add the second host.  We've created shared storage(VDISK1) which both ESX hosts have access.

ESX Host1

- Shared Storage (VDISK1)
- vCenter Server (Appliance)

ESX Host2

- Shared Storage (VDISK1)

Searching the net suggested unmounting the storage from the 2nd host prior to adding it to vCenter Server, but that has not worked.  Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank You,
Eric

** SOLVED **

Just in case anyone else runs into this.  We ended up having to re-build the problem host.  Once rebuilt, we added it to the Data Center.  Then we installed the storage driver and added the shared storage.

Comment: SOLVED - See comments above.

Comment: Please post your resolution as an answer below and [mark it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a Dell VRTX and ran into the same issue. I resolved the issue by briefly removing the storage access for the ESXi host with the issue:

1. Shut down the ESXi host with the issue.
2. Login to the VRTX CMC and remove the storage access for the ESXi host with the issue.
3. Power on the ESXi host
4. Connect the ESXi host to vCenter. It should succeed without the storage conflict.
5. Login to the VRTX CMC and add the storage access for the ESXi host.
6. Rescan the datastores and the previously removed volumes should be accessible.

The issue did not re-occur after a few ESXi shutdown or reboot cycles. All Good.